# seasonal ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, tidyverse, axis-labels

I am looking at data from Nov to April and would like to have a plot starting from Nov to April. Below is my sample code to screen out month of interests.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata = data.frame(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="days"), A = runif(730,10,50))
colnames(mydata) = c("Date", "A")
DF = mydata %>%
     mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>%
     filter(Month == 11 | Month == 12 | Month == 01 | Month == 02 | Month == 03 | Month == 04)
```

I tried to re-order the data starting at month 11 followed by month 12 and then month 01,02,03,and,04. I used the code `factor(Month, levels = c(11,12,01,02,03,04))` along with the code above but it didn't work. 
I wanted a plot that starts at month Nov and ends on April. The following code gave me attached plot

```
ggplot(data = DF, aes(Month,A))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ facet_wrap(~Year, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Right now, the plot is starting at January all the way to December- I dont want this. I want the plot starting at November, and all the way to April. I tried to label the plot using `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b", date_breaks = "month", name = "Month")` which didn't work. Any help would

Comment: *"Right now, the plot is starting at January all the way to December- I dont want this. I want the plot starting at November, and all the way to April."* But you're `facet_wrap`ping by `Year`. How do you expect that to affect the Nov to Apr ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted Month to character before applying factor() and it worked.

```
DF = mydata %>%
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>%
  filter(Month %in% c(11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4)) %>%
  mutate(Month = sprintf("%02d", Month)) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("11","12","01","02","03","04")))

ggplot(data = DF, aes(Month,A))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ facet_wrap(~Year, ncol = 2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note, your solution is plotting the months out of order.  For example Dec 2010 is plotted before Jan 2010.

Comment: Yes, I just kept her solution and improved what she was asking. She has to decide if she wants a better layout. I agree it's not the ideal, too.

Answer (score 0):

user2332849 answer is close but does introduce an error.  The bar are not in the correct order.  For example for 2010, it plot is showing November and December's data prior to the beginning of the year's data.  In order to plot in the proper order the year will need adjustment so that the calendar starts on month 11 and goes to month 4.

```
#Convert month to Factor and set desired order
DF$Month<- factor(DF$Month, levels=c(11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4))
#Adjust the year to match the year of the beginning of series
#For example assign Jan, Feb, Mar and April to prior year
DF$Year<-ifelse(as.integer(as.character(DF$Month)) <6, DF$Year-1, DF$Year)

#plot
ggplot(data = DF, aes(Month,A))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~Year, ncol = 3)
```

In the plot below the first 4 months of 2010 is shifted to become the last 4 periods of the prior year.  And the last 2 months of 2011 is ready for the first 4 months of 2012.

[image]

Comment: I am looking at seasonal plot, which in my case Winter season starts at November of previous year to April of the following year. That means, my one complete winter season is Nov-Dec of year 2010 and Jan-Apr of year 2011. Having said that, i should have one season here but i wanted to see how we can re-arrange the data according to my defined season.

Comment: @hydro, the plot above does that.  The 2010 winter season above is a plot of Nov-Dec of 2010 and Jan-Apr of 2011.